# What 3rd party OpenVPN clients or addons are there?

Tags: open-source, security, privacy, vpn

Each commercial OpenVPN provider typically has their own branded VPN client for their users.  However, there is also the [OpenVPN client from OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html).

Are there any other vendor-neutral OpenVPN clients or programs that enhance OpenVPN functionality?

**Features I would be looking for:**

- Easy Windows 10 autostartup; both the GUI and specific profiles
- [Autokill](https://www.bestvpn.com/blog/5142/5-ways-protect-vpn-connection-fails/) functionality
- Prevent network access until the VPN is up
- Well supported and/or relevant updates.  For example if there is another [Heartbleed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed).
- Works on Windows (7 - 10)

**Nice to haves:**

- Gratis/free/low cost
- Multi platform (Linux, Android, etc.)
- Passed a security/code autid

**Benefits of a vendor-neutral client:**

- Increases OPSEC: it's just a VPN client and does not have branding
- You can use the same client to connect to a commercial VPN provider as well as to your own OPenVPN network/server
- You can connect to different providers with a few clicks
- Increases `l33t hax0r factor` by not running "stock"

Answer (score 1):

### Securepoint SSL VPN Client

I have come across [SecurePoint](https://sourceforge.net/projects/securepoint/), which is a vendor-neutral OpenVPN client.  I have not tested it yet, but it looks promising.

[image]

- Made in Germany.  A lot of security, privacy, and anonymity software is coming from Germany.
- Open Source ([Github](https://github.com/Securepoint/openvpn-client))
- Talked about on the [AirVPN forums](https://airvpn.org/topic/10632-securepoint-openvpn-open-source-client-for-windows/)
- Gratis/free
- Regular updates means it's being actively maintained.  Last update was a few weeks ago.
- Based on the OpenVPN client.

### OpenVPN MI GUI

I have come across [OpenVPN MI GUI](http://openvpn-mi-gui.inside-security.de/).  This is a replacement GUI for the OpenVPN client.  It is not a complete OpenVPN client, it just adds functionality to the OpenVPN service that is installed but you're probably not using.  I have not tested this yet, but it looks promising.

[image]

**Features**

- Made in Germany.  A lot of security, privacy, and anonymity software is coming from Germany.
- Does not appear to be Open Source
- Gratis/free
- Updates every year or so
- Runs on Windows

**Drawbacks**

- Doesn't support all the latest features of OpenVPN 2.3
- Windows only

## From the author:

**Purpose**

The original OpenVPN GUI encounters the following problems especially in enterprise or high security environments:

```
Users have no administrative rights, but unprivileged users do not have enough permissions to add and delete routes.
The GUI will exit on user logout closing all VPN tunnels and preventing e.g. remote VNC logins by an administrator.
The OpenVPN service wrapper can start one or more OpenVPN instances with enough rights, but the GUI has no control over them.
OpenVPN running as a service can not request passwords for certificates or user authentication data from the user directly or through the GUI.
```

The OpenVPN MI GUI talks to the management interfaces of OpenVPN instances started through the service wrapper and can overcome the above problems.
Differences

**The major differences to the original GUI are:**

```
Handling of OpenVPN clients was replaced with management interface support including port and state auto detection, input reassembly, command queueing, log display, password requests...
Proxy settings support was removed since it can't be passed on to OpenVPN over the management interface.
Byte count displays were added to status windows.
start and stop command line options were added for batch script use.
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN MI GUI:
http://openvpn-mi-gui.inside-security.de/

> OpenVPN MI GUI is a Windows graphical user interface for the OpenVPN client management interface.
>
> It is based on the OpenVPN GUI by Mathias Sundman (version 1.0.3 from August 2005) which is shipped with OpenVPN, but had large parts of the backend adapted by Boris Wesslowski from Inside Security GmbH, commissioned by Conergy AG.
>
> OpenVPN versions 2.1.x, 2.2.x are supported. OpenVPN 2.3.x too, but not all new features are supported yet.

And in contrast to what was mentioned on a previous post, it is actually Open Source (GPL), just not on github. :-)

Comment: Chris, please explain how your solution fits each requirement in the question's bullet list.